# Generating key-value pairs from <select> field, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<select>` field. Using jQuery, I want get programmatically the value and the name from the option inside the select, and create a variable that contain the key-value pair of each option field.

For example, starting from this:

```
<select>
   <option value="option1">item1 </option>
   <option value="option2">item2</option>
</select>
```

I want generate the vabiable:

```
var obj = {
  "option1": "item1",
  "option2": "item2"
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var obj = {}; //create an object
$("select").children().each(function () {
    obj[this.value] = this.innerHTML
})
```

[**Working Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/zK7y2/4/)

Comment: You shouldn't use `new Object()` since, in theory, the global name `Object` could be clobbered. Instead the first line should say `var obj = {};`

Comment: It is a rather rare occurrence to overwrite the global `Object` constructor (yes, I get the "in theory" part), but a more important aspect is that `{}` is much shorter to type and can be optimized at parse time by modern JS interpreters (unlike `new Object()` which has to look for the Object constructor through lexical scope as it may have been shadowed).